# Get Old Value from table using entitydatasource during updating event (C# ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to upload a new image to the server then delete the old image off the server however, when using the code below, the string used to delete the file is null, how would I accomplish this?

Code:

```
protected void BandEditorEntityDataSource_Updating(object sender, EntityDataSourceChangingEventArgs e)
{
    Band myBand = (Band)e.Entity;
    FileUpload bandlogo = (FileUpload)BandDetailsView.FindControl("BandLogoEditFileUpload");
    if (bandlogo.HasFile)
    {
        string oldbandlogopath = myBand.BandLogoUrl; //<- Returns null value
        myBand.BandLogoUrl = fileupload(bandlogo, "~/Images/Uploaded/Band/Logo/");
        string oldbandlogodelfile = Server.MapPath(oldbandlogopath);
        System.IO.File.Delete(oldbandlogodelfile);
    }
}
```

File Upload Method (it seems to work because it uploads the file to the server but I'm not sure if the database is actually receiving the update since it throws the error):

```
private string fileupload(FileUpload fileUploadControl, string virtualFolders)
{
    string virtualFolder = virtualFolders;
    string physicalFolder = Server.MapPath(virtualFolder);
    string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileUploadControl.FileName);
    fileUploadControl.SaveAs(System.IO.Path.Combine(physicalFolder, fileName + extension));
    string returnUrl = virtualFolder + fileName + extension;
    return returnUrl;
}
```

Comment: Ok, so you generate BanLogoUrl on save as well and save the **url** in database? So, when Band returns from database you expect it contains value inside BandLogoUrl, right? Have you checked that BandLogoUrl when data is fetched?

Comment: @AlenaKastsiukavets Yes the method saves the picture to the folder specified and then it returns the url of the saved image.  I tested this on a sample page and it works as expected.  When I fetch the data from another page the image is there.

Comment: You mean the image url is inside BandLogoUrl? or you just see that image is displayed on the page?

Comment: @AlenaKastsiukavets Yes the image url is stored inside the BandLogoUrl

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should have two method _Updating when update starts and _Updated when update is finished. Hope you will see your url in _Updated method

Comment: Do you have some sample code, I'm not quite sure what you mean.  The data is already there from a previous picture.  What I am trying to do is:  I have a previous picture that was uploaded earlier (inserted into the database manually at this point) and that value points to an already existing picture.  What I want the above code to do is to get that already existing picture and delete it after setting the database value to a new picture (and of course upload it).  Any Ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Seems I misunderstood a little, could you provide your fileupload method?

Comment: Updated question to include the fileupload method (not sure if that is the correct way to implement it)